# Mac OS X does not send cookies to WebDAV resource

Tags: macos, webdav, ntlm

my WebDAV server (based on Tomcat's DefaultServlet) requires NTLM authentication. The server works fine with Windows clients.

A Mac (OS X 10.6.8) client performs the HTTP authentication handshake on each request, when I connect the Mac Finder to the server. This is because it does not send the session cookie back to my server. Is there a configuration option that I can set to tell it to accept and send the session cookie?

When I connect via Safari to the server, the session cookie is sent.

Thanks in advance.

Wolfgang

Comment: Generally webdav clients do not support cookies, and generally webdav servers don't use them. Instead you normally need to ensure that server side authentication is efficient enough to authenticate each request without incurring performance penalties. Some sort of caching is usually appropriate.

Have you looked at http://milton.io ? Its used very widely with Apple and iOS devices.

Comment: Thank you, brad. I will have a look at milton.